# jQuery - add active state for each associated data-attribute

Tags: jquery

In the code I am adding a unique identifier for each item when you click the button. On each `input` I have a `data-type` that has an associated `.menu` with the **same name** in that menu's `data-id`.

This code correctly adds the unique identifier to the input's `data-type`:

```
$(this).attr("data-type", $(this).attr("data-type") + "_" + uniqueId);
```

But this code returns `undefined_x` the menu's `data-id` and does not get the menu's data-id value:

```
$(this).closest(".item").find(".menu, .menu__wrap").attr("data-id", $(this).attr("data-id") + "_" + uniqueId);
```

How do I change the function for the `data-id` to not return `undefined`, but the correct value just like the `data-type` on the `input`?

> Example: If I clone the item 3 times I want the "shapes" input to be `data-type="shapes_3"`(which the code currently does) but then I also want the
>   "shapes" menu's to get: `data-id="shapes_3"` so that they match and
>   the active class function will work correctly.

```js
var uniqueId = 1;
$(function() {
  $(".clone").click(function() {
    var copy = $("#item").clone(true);
    var formId = "item_" + uniqueId;
    copy.attr("id", formId);
    $("#list").append(copy);
    $("#" + formId)
      .find("input,select")
      .each(function() {
        $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "_" + uniqueId);
        $(this).attr("data-type", $(this).attr("data-type") + "_" + uniqueId);

        $(this).closest(".item").find(".menu, .menu__wrap")
          .attr("data-id", $(this).attr("data-id") + "_" + uniqueId);

        $(this)
          .closest("label")
          .attr("for", $(this).attr("id"));
      });
    uniqueId++;
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".clone").trigger("click");
  $(".clone").trigger("click");
  $(".clone").trigger("click");
});
$('input[name="studio"]').change(function() {
  var id = $(this).data("type");
  $(".menu[data-id=" + id + "]").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
  $(".menu__wrap[data-id=" + id + "]").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
});
$('input[name="studio"]').change();
```

```css
.menu {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid
}

.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clone">Clone</button>
<div id="list">
  <div class="item" action="" id="item">
    <div class="menu" data-id="colors">
      <div class="menu__wrap" data-id="colors"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu" data-id="shapes">
      <div class="menu__wrap" data-id="shapes"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu" data-id="animals">
      <div class="menu__wrap" data-id="animals"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input--studio">
      <label for="blue" data-type="colors">Colors
      <input type="checkbox" id="blue" name="studio" data-type="colors"/>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input--studio">
      <label for="red" data-type="colors">Shapes
      <input type="checkbox" id="red" name="studio" data-type="shapes"/>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input--studio">
      <label for="dog" data-type="animals">Animals</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dog" name="studio" data-type="animals" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do. You want to add the `data-id` attribute to the input elements with the same value and sequence as `data-type`?

Comment: @EternalHour the `.active` class should be added to each item's menu & menu__wrap if each item's checkbox `data-type` matches the `data-id` from the menu & menu__wrap. The issue is when the the unique identifier is added, I am getting undefined on the data-id of the menu when it should have the same value as the corresponding data-type.

Comment: That is two different issues and questions.

Comment: "I am getting undefined on the data-id of the menu when it should have the same value as the corresponding data-type." Why not assign the same value to the `data-id` attribute that you are assigning to the `data-type` attribute?

Comment: I have updated the question with an example which may help better explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand exactly what you need, you can solve the issue this way.

```
// get the original data-type from current input before it is modified
var dataType = $(this).attr("data-type");

$(this).attr("data-type", $(this).attr("data-type") + "_" + uniqueId);

// look for the closest menu item with the same data-id value and update it
$(this).closest(".item").find(".menu__wrap[data-id='" + dataType + "']")
.attr("data-id", dataType + "_" + uniqueId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move the line:

```
$(this).closest(".item").find(".menu, .menu__wrap")
          .attr("data-id", $(this).attr("data-id") + "_" + uniqueId);
```

to outside the event and replace it with

```
copy.find(".menu, .menu__wrap").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("data-id", $(this).attr("data-id") + "_" + uniqueId);
});
```

```js
var uniqueId = 1;
$(function() {
  $(".clone").click(function() {
    var copy = $("#item").clone(true);
    var formId = "item_" + uniqueId;
    copy.attr("id", formId);
    $("#list").append(copy);
    $("#" + formId)
      .find("input,select")
      .each(function() {

        $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "_" + uniqueId);
        $(this).attr("data-type", $(this).attr("data-type") + "_" + uniqueId);
          
        $(this)
          .closest("label")
          .attr("for", $(this).attr("id"));
      });
      
    copy.find(".menu, .menu__wrap").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("data-id", $(this).attr("data-id") + "_" + uniqueId);
    });
      
    uniqueId++;
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
//  $(".clone").trigger("click");
//  $(".clone").trigger("click");
//  $(".clone").trigger("click");
});
$('input[name="studio"]').change(function() {
  var id = $(this).data("type");
  $(".menu[data-id=" + id + "]").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
  $(".menu__wrap[data-id=" + id + "]").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
});
$('input[name="studio"]').change();
```

```css
.menu {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid
}

.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clone">Clone</button>
<div id="list">
  <div class="item" action="" id="item">
    <div class="menu" data-id="colors">
      <div class="menu__wrap" data-id="colors"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu" data-id="shapes">
      <div class="menu__wrap" data-id="shapes"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu" data-id="animals">
      <div class="menu__wrap" data-id="animals"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input--studio">
      <label for="blue" data-type="colors">Colors
      <input type="checkbox" id="blue" name="studio" data-type="colors"/>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input--studio">
      <label for="red" data-type="colors">Shapes
      <input type="checkbox" id="red" name="studio" data-type="shapes"/>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input--studio">
      <label for="dog" data-type="animals">Animals</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dog" name="studio" data-type="animals" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is giving `data-id="shapes_2_2_2"` but should only be `data-id="shapes_2"`

Comment: @KyleUnderhill Oh sorry, I forgot it. I've updated my answer! You can check again

Comment: Still experiencing the same issue with each cloned item